# How to split an array based on the condition `+1`?

Tags: php

How can I split an array of sequential numbers on gaps in the sequence?

The sequence is `n = x + 1` (*where `x` is the previous number in the sequence*)

For example:

```
$array  = [1,2,3,4,6,7,9,10,11];
$result = [[1,2,3,4], [6,7], [9,10,11]];
```

Comment: What is the condition used here to determine the second arrangement?  And can you include your attempt?

Comment: @Progrock looks to me that it's `+1`??

Comment: @Steven too many assumptions there.  And mathematically your definition of the sequence is poor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach:

```
<?php
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11];

$i = 0;
$last = null;
foreach($array as $n) {
    if(!is_null($last) && ($n - $last != 1)) {
        $i++;
    }
    $output[$i][] = $n;
    $last = $n;
}

var_dump([[1,2,3,4],[6,7],[9,10,11]] === $output);
```

Output:

```
true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$original_array = [1,2,3,4,6,7,9,10,11];
$result_array   = [];


// initialise last value
$last_value = FALSE;                                             


// Loop through each value in original array
foreach($original_array as $value){

    // Check to see if the current value is one more than the current
    // value and that it isn't the first value being checked.
    if($last_value && $value == ++$last_value){
        // Add value to last element of `$result_array` if pre-requisites are TRUE
        $result_array[array_key_last($result_array)][] = $value;
    }
    else{
        // Create a new array in `$result_array` if `if` evaluates to FALSE
        $result_array[] = [$value];
    }


    // Update value ready for next iteration of loop
    $last_value = $value;
}


// Print results
print_r($result_array);

/* Output:

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 7
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 11
        )

)

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the input array is indexed, you can simply subtract 1 from the current iteration's index to access the previous value (not need to cache the previously encountered value).

If the current index is not zero and the previous value is more than 1 step behind the current value, then increment `$index`.  `$index` determines which group the value will be pushed into.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/S8NBp))

```
$result = [];
$index = 0;
foreach ($array as $i => $value) {
    $result[$index += ($i && $value !== $array[$i - 1] + 1)][] = $value;
}
var_export($result);
```

Or:

```
foreach ($array as $i => $value) {
    $index += ($i && $value !== $array[$i - 1] + 1);
    $result[$index][] = $value;
}
```

Or:

```
foreach ($array as $i => $value) {
    $result[$index += ($value - ($array[$i - 1] ?? $value) !== 1)][] = $value;
}
```

Or:

```
foreach ($array as $i => $value) {
    $index += ($value - ($array[$i - 1] ?? $value) !== 1);
    $result[$index][] = $value;
}
```